# C# URI with space

Tags: c#, visual-studio, win-universal-app

```
myMediaElement.Source = new Uri("http://asdfggfadf.net/fdsfsdfsd 9");
```

Already tried many solutions that i found here, but did not solved the problem;
Maybe i'm doing something wrong.
Any help would be great.
Thanks in advance ;-)

Comment: What IS your problem?

Comment: The problem is that the uri with "spaces" do not work; right!?

Comment: Please see [ask], no need for the exclamation marks, #SOReadyToHelp

Answer (score 2):

Use `myMediaElement.Source = new Uri(HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://asdfggfadf.net/fdsfsdfsd 9"));`

Comment: thanks, but: "the Name 'HttpUtility' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Thanks @JeremyThompson I saw that solution in other places too and seems to be the correct answer but i cannot make it work. I already reference it but then the problem is UrlEncode and i cannot solve it.

Comment: What's the error message mate? Can you call any other functions in the HttpUtility namespace now you've referenced the DLL?

Answer (score 1):

```
myMediaElement.Source = new Uri(Uri.EscapeUriString("http://asdfggfadf.net/fdsfsdfsd 9"));
```

If it not help then the problem isn't in space.

Comment: Thanks for your time. It's working fine with streams without spaces, so that is really the problem.